# Bounding Box Search in JDO and GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

i have my current lat,lon
and i want to make Bounding Box Search in GAE data store to get every nearest location to my current point .

i want the bounding box to be 1 km around my point

how can i do this ??

Answer (score 0):

Check this example: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/geosearch.html

It is in Python, but the discussion of the associated problems and ways to implement precomputed boxes could be helpful to you.